# Is it appropriate to ask a question I have already found an answer for just to get it on the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

Some questions are easy to find answers with a Google search. However, they may not have an answer, or they might even have been asked here on the site.

Is it desirable to ask the question here to add to the library of information or should we only ask questions here that we have not found answers for elsewhere?

Comment: There's a fine line between trivial and interesting. Trivial is always easily found via a Google search, but sometimes interesting is too. Trivial questions bother some people sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a good, on-topic question, yes.

To a certain extent, people are encouraged to ask and answer their own questions.

Questions and answers should be judged on their own merits, not on whether or not the one asking already found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but be careful.

Flimzy is certainly correct regarding self-answers.  Quoting from the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer):

> Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

However, I'd caution you to be careful regarding *which* questions you ask here.  Just because it hasn't been asked here doesn't mean that it *should* be asked here.  Stack Exchange's mission is to make the internet a better place, not to answer every conceivable question.  That means that if Wikipedia (for example) already contains the answer, asking the question here may not be helpful.

Sometimes easily accessible online sources provide the desired information, but not in a helpful way: perhaps there are no sources, or it's poorly written, or it's only on a random blog.  If so, then go ahead and ask here—answers to the question in such cases can easily "make the internet a better place."

So in short, the answer is "yes and no." Don't *just* ask questions because they haven't been asked yet.  But don't let "I already know the answer" be all that keeps you from asking a good question.